# How can I smoothly combine two equations?

Tags: limits

I had an equation $g = -3d$, but I didn't want $g$ to ever be smaller than $-8H$, so I changed it to $g = \max(-3d, -8H)$. This works, but it's a hard cut off... $g$ follows a certain line as $d$ increases, until all of a sudden it gets pegged at $-8H$. Is there a different modification I could make to the equation that would smooth out the transition?

Comment: do you still want $-8H$ after a while but like to blend in smoothly? if so you can use a parabola to connect the slant line to the horizontal line $-8H$

Answer (score 0):

You could try the log-sum-exp function as a smooth approximation to the max. Define
$$
   f(x) = \log( e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\dots+e^{x_n} )
$$
which satisfies 
$\max(x_1, +dots, x_n)   \le f(x) \le  \max(x_1, \dots, x_n)+\log n<4.

A reference is Stephen Boyd & Lieven Vandenberghe:  "Convex Optimization", page 72.